# "Item not updated" when try to change category properties

Tags: categories, updates, description

When I try to change some properties for some categories (in most categories it works without any issues), like category name, or description, I see that it is not updated, and I get an issue `"Item not updated"`.
What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to update your category's name to one that already exists. Duplicates are not allowed - either of other categories or of tags.

Comment: And how do you explain the fact that even when I try to change description of the category, I also have this issue?

Comment: I cannot, offhand, unless the duplicate categories were created directly using SQL, and thereby bypassed the duplicate error message initially. I would check for duplicate category/tag slugs, as this is the most likely explanation.